# RMI and JDO: How interoperable are they?

Tags: java, rmi, jdo

I plan to write an application using RMI that uses JDO as a database. I am thinking of taking the same classes and both compiling RMI stubs and enhancing them for use with JDO. Thus, clients communicate with the server using the same objects that are stored in the database. Is this possible?

Comment: I saw your other question, too. My last RMI program is a couple of years ago, so I don't remember all the RMI details and can't give a really good answer, but I looks strange to me to make the domain objects to remote objects. Maybe an architecture with a well defined server interface and maybe Data Transfer Objects (DTOs) would be a better approach. Also I recommend to become clear about the requirements first. Secondly trying to satisfy your requirements technically will lead you into the right direction. Antoher alternative: Message passing e.g. with Akka (www.akka.io). Good luck.

Comment: There are many more practical details to JDO objects than just domain data. There are lifecycle methods (implementing JDO-speciic interfaces), helper code which creates a dependency on JDO implementation itself, etc. You are heading in just the direction I have mentioned to you in your other question: you will have the complete set of dependency JARs on both the client and the server.

Answer (score 0):

I've not used JDO before, but if I was desgining it, I would make these details unknown to the client.

The client shouldn't care where or how the objects it is requesting come from.  This allows you to define the interface (or interfaces) that the client will be allowed to interact with, but freeing you to implement as you see fit.

The problem with exposing the client to the details means that it's difficult (if not impossible) to move to a different implementation later on.

To my mind, I would treat it much like any other remote API (like a web RPC for example), where you have a series of well defined interfaces that allows the client to interact with the server, but keep the details of how that interaction actually works on the server side.

This separates the area of responsibilities and if you design it well, means that if you need to change the server model in the future it should have little to no effect on the client, as you have a well defined contract that you can work through

So my answer would be, yes it can be done, but no, the client should know nothing about how it is done

IMHO

Answer (score 0):

This should work if you make sure to detach JDOs before they get serialized over RMI. See http://db.apache.org/jdo/attach_detach.html

Comment: But can I attach them later and have them still be remote-accessible?

Comment: Yes, although attaching is useful only on the server in the scenario where your remote client made an update to the JDO and you want to persist the changes in your data store.